# How can I generate uniform randomly integer number without repetition in C++

Tags: c++, g++, visual-studio-2015

I want to generate a random integer which follows uniform distribution without repetition. For example, I will generate 6 uniform number by this code

```
 vector<int> container;
 container.reserve(lossNum);
 std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator it;
 // Our Random Generator
 std::mt19937 eng{ std::random_device{}() };
 int max_num=6
 for (int i = 0; i<max_num; i++) {
     unsigned int q = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int>{ 0, max_num }(eng);

     do {
         q = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int>{ 0, max_num }(eng);
         it = std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), q);
     } while (it != container.end());

     container.push_back(q);
 }
```

And I run above code 120.000 time and draw the figure. But the figure does not show uniform distribution. What is problem in my code? I am using visual studio 2015 to run it.

In addition, if i run in linux(Ubuntu) environment. How can I modify the above code for standard C++? Thanks

[image]

This is my code

Comment: Since you don't have the word "random" in your text, `container.push_back(i);` will do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, It must be random

Comment: @user8430 I don't know how this can help, but you're requesting a random number two times in a row - before and in `do-while` loop. Try declaring `unsigned int q;` without initializing it to a random number.

Comment: [Fisher–Yates_shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) may help.

Answer (score 4):

1. Code example

Looking at your code, it looks like you reinvent wheel. MSVC 2015 should support `std::shuffle` so you can do the same with:

```
int max_num = 6;
// Create vector
std::vector<int> container(max_num);
// Fill it with numbers 0, 1, ..., max_num - 1)
std::iota(container.begin(), container.end(), 0)
// Create random engine generator
std::mt19937 eng{ std::random_device{}() };
// shuffle it!!
std::shuffle(container.begin(), container.end(), eng);
```

All the nasty stuff is done and not by you !!

2. Randomness

Do you really want to generate 6 number in [0, 6]?
Why not 7 number to have all of them?

I tested your code on my computer with 120 000 repetition and I have:
0 is missing 17335 times
1 is missing 16947 times
2 is missing 17054 times
3 is missing 17116 times
4 is missing 17330 times
5 is missing 17114 times
6 is missing 17105 times

It looks to be uniform here but I use g++. May be it is a problem with msvc std library but I can't give you more information as I do not use it.

Comment: Could you show above code to g++. I want to build it in Ubuntu

Comment: I think all the code is already there. If you want to use `std::shuffle`, the above code should do the job. Otherwise, I tested your code with the do...while loop.

Comment: I think your code look different with my question. I just want to generate x number (x maybe 3 or 2....) but less than 6. So the container must be adjusted by x. Can you edit your code as my requirement

Comment: I don't know how to generate less values. You can just pick x first elements using : `container.resize(x)` after shuffling. If you have to handle really huge sequences, you may have a look at http://blog.quarkslab.com/unique-random-number-set-computation.html

Answer (score 1):

Never do that:

```
do {
     q = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int>{ 0, max_num }(eng);
     it = std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), q);
 } while (it != container.end());
```

You are picking an element, and then rejecting if you have already selected it previously. Computationally-wise, that's a no-no.

What you desire is something called Knuth shuffle (aka Fisher–Yates shuffle).
Such algorithm allows you to randomly pick elements of a vector (here, a vector with your 6 numbers [0;6[), without replacement.

"Fisher–Yates shuffling is similar to randomly picking numbered tickets (combinatorics: distinguishable objects) out of a hat without replacement until there are none left." in [Knuth Shuffle wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Code for suffle:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Arrange the N elements of ARRAY in random order.
Only effective if N is much smaller than RAND_MAX;
if this may not be the case, use a better random
number generator. */
void shuffle(int *array, size_t n)
{
    if (n > 1) {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);
            int t = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. but I will work it in Ubuntu. So some API function in Visual studio 2015 cannot use, such as std::shuffle

Comment: Yes, it will work  cross-platform (both windows and Ubuntu). I've just added code to the previous response.